# Add js file at the end of merged js file magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am using `Magento 1.9.3.` I merged js and CSS files.

I want to add order or if possible add js file at the end of the merged js file.

is this possible in merged js ?

Comment: is that any librerary which is online avaliable or its custom js ??

Comment: its custom js i want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your `xyz.js` and then add it again in your `local.xml`. Be sure to do that *after* all other js files have been added:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- add your other js files -->
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/xyz.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/xyz.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```